# Convert text to smileys without refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I just saw that Facebook provides a new feature in its messaging that is converting text directly into smiley without reloading the page. So I would like to reproduce the same system using jquery and html5. Currently I have no idea how to create this system, any idea ?

Code use to convert into smileys :

```
 var e = $('body');
e.html(
    e.html()
    .replace(/\s:\)/g, " <img src='http://img/img.gif' />")

);
```

Comment: So you need to have code listening for keypresses and matching the text.

Comment: Do you have a question for us?

Comment: @epascarello, so I need to register the smileys code in javascript function ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There does not seem to be a problem but rather an entire implementation to build here

Comment: @ewan Have you seen [`emojify.js`](http://hassankhan.me/emojify.js/)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, this will be convert when we are writting ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code: (https://jsfiddle.net/zLj9ckhq)

```
<form method="POST">
 <input id="msg">
 <button type="button">send</button>
</form>

 <script>
  var smilley = {
  ':)': 'imgSrc1',
  ':(': 'imgSrc1',
 };

$('button').click(function(){
  var content = $('#msg').val();
  $.each(smilley, function(key,val) {
    console.log(key)
    content = content.replace(key,val);
 });

 alert(content);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really useful.